# How to create a bitly link that has dynamic customer data in the URL?

Tags: ampscript, url, urlhacking, sms, hyperlink

I am trying to create an SMS message for customers that has a 'confirm with us' bitly link inside the text that will take them to a landing page which should pass their ID from the url to CRM so that we can see they clicked it.

> https://www.veteransfirst.com/email/appointment-confirmation?utm_campaign=vf-journey-confirmed-appointment&Id=%%=v(@EventId)=%%

This is the full-length url we are trying to shorten. It will take you to the correct landing page but it does not populate that click in CRM which we need. Is there a way for me to use a bitly link in a text that is dynamic to customer id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `BITLY_TOKEN` [access token to make an API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/mobileVariables.htm) and shorten the URL while still using AMPscript to make the URL dynamic.

```
%%[
SET @URL = TRIM(HTTPGet(Concat("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=BITLY_TOKEN&format=txt&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/mobile/conf.php?mobile=",MOBILE_NUMBER)))
]%%
```

> Replace the text BITLY_TOKEN with your own token. You can encode
>   mobile numbers or tags in the URL for later usage in reports. A high
>   volume of calls (over 10,000) to the bit.ly API may exceed the limits
>   of a free account. If you include these a large number of unique URLs
>   via bit.ly in your sends, consider upgrading to an enterprise bit.ly
>   account to ensure you can use a higher volume of API calls.

Comment: be forewarned bit.ly has a rate limit that MobileConnect can easily surpass